# jQuery click event stop propagation can't get to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, propagation

I've got a popup that I don't want to close unless you click off of it, however it closes whenever I click on it as well. It shouldn't close when you click inside the div with the class of "create-album-container"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

////posts menu
$(".container").on("contextmenu", ".photos-bottom .albums li", function(e) {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault; 
$('.create-album-container').hide();
$('.photos-bottom .albums li#'+id+' .create-album-container').show();

return false;   
});



$("body").click(function (event) {
     $('.create-album-container').hide();
});

});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault` must be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `e.preventDefault();` - it is a function

And did you try to add

```
$('.create-album-container').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
});
```

?

Comment: preventDefault works as it should, it's the stopPropagation part that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @DylanCross    But stopPropagation is attached to the right click, it is not fully related to your question.

Comment: That never even occurred to me, however i'm not having any success either way

Comment: @DylanCross     So, did you try to prevent propagation for the left click? If yes then do you have a link to the page with your code?

Comment: I'm not sure that `.stopPropagation()` will work when you're using delegated events: by the time the event is handled it has already propagated up to the ".container" element, so I think all you can do is stop it propagating even further up. Also, returning `false` from the event handler will automatically do `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()`...

Comment: @nnnnnn        but that is what he needs - not to pass it to the body click listener. "returning false" just an overhead :)))

Comment: Actually I got it figured out, thanks.